# Is there general algorithm for us to cluster entities in DBpedia using their properties?

Tags: algorithm, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

As we know, there are so many entities in Dbpedia. Sometimes, we need to cluster(or classify) those entities for some reasons, such as summarization[1].
The simplest way for us to cluster those entities is by leveraging their types( or classes). For example, the type of entity Donald Trump is Person. However, we found it's not enough that only using types to summarize those entities. We want to generalize it to some other properties( or predicates) of entities to help cluster. But it seems like that there is not plenty of related work. Anyone has some advice? Is there any general algorithm for that? Or what keywords should I search for in a search engine?

Edit:
I was not clear enough. To be accurate, it's not clustering. But  I just couldn't find a more exact word for it. What I want to do is, as I said before, when doing summarization, we can replace Donald Trump by Person because he has a property called 'type' and the value is 'Person', but it's just an extremely simple method. May be we can replace Donald Trump with Male, since he has a property called 'gender', and the value is 'male'. But not every property is suitable, considering the property ‘postalCode’ of New York , apparently we can't replace new york with 10001. So what I want to figure out is, is there any method to find such properties that are suitable for summarizing?

[1]Cheng G, Liu D, Qu Y. Efficient Algorithms for Association Finding and Frequent Association Pattern Mining[C]//International Semantic Web Conference. Springer International Publishing, 2016: 119-134.([link](http://www-kasm.nii.ac.jp/iswc2016/papers/paper_M25_.pdf))

Comment: I know it's kind of off topic here. Maybe you can suggest me a better place to ask such questions.

Comment: What do you mean by a general algorithm? IF you're doing clustering, then adding properties in addition to the classes are just more features for each object you're clustering.

Comment: I've edited my question. sorry for not being clear@AKSW

Comment: May I ask what the use-case is? I was working on *entity summarization* in RDF, so I'm wondering what you're trying to achieve. What's the input, what is the expected output? Regarding your gender example, you have to consider the whole triple, resp. predicate + object - this always forms some kind of concept describing the entity. this also works for the postal code, it would be "something having postcalCode 10001". That you can use just "male" is because you know implicitly that then the topic itself is gender, but that's human knowledge. Thus, it would be "something with gender male"

Comment: We have implemented a system that can return the associations of several given query entities. The associations can be understood as a lot of subgraphs of  the knowledge graph, i.e DBpedia, which connected all those query entities. But most times the number of subgraphs can be quite large, thus it will be hard for users to interpret them. So we decided to abstract those associations subgraphs as patterns, which means replacing the non-query entities in the subgraphs with some classes. Such as replace Trump with Person or Male. Then we can only return users with the most frequent patterns.

Comment: So the problem is about which properties can be depended on to cluster the entities. I know a little about entity summarization, maybe it's kind of similar here since you need to decide what properties to choose when summarize an entity. @AKSW